# Pickling an unbound method in Python 3

Tags: python, methods, python-3.x, pickle

I would like to pickle an unbound method in Python 3.x. I'm getting this error:

```
>>> class A:
...     def m(self):
...         pass
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(A.m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    pickle.dumps(A.m)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\pickle.py", line 1358, in dumps
    Pickler(f, protocol, fix_imports=fix_imports).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'function'>: attribute lookup builtins.function failed
```

Does anyone have experience with this?

---

Note: In Python 2.x it's also impossible to pickle unbound methods by default; I managed to do it there in some weird way I don't understand: I wrote a reducer with the `copy_reg` module for the MethodType class, which covers both bound and unbound methods. But the reducer only solved the case of the bound method, because it depended on `my_method.im_self`. Mysteriously it has also caused Python 2.x to be able to pickle unbound methods. This does not happen on Python 3.x.

Answer (score 7):

This cannot be done directly because in Python 3 unbound method type is gone: it is just a function:

```
>>> print (type (A.m))
<class 'function'>
```

Python functions are not bound to a class, so it is impossible to tell what class `A.m` belongs to just by looking at the expression result.

Depending on what exactly you need, pickling/unpickling a tuple of (class, method-name) might be good enough:

```
>>> print (pickle.loads (pickle.dumps ((A, 'm'))))
... (<class '__main__.A'>, 'm')
```

You can get the method (function) from here simply by using `getattr()`:

```
>>> cls, method = pickle.loads (pickle.dumps ((A, 'm')))
>>> print (getattr (cls, method))
... <function m at 0xb78878ec>
```

Comment: Are you saying that on Python 3,  given an unbound method, there's no way of knowing where that method was defined?

Comment: Yes.  Try declaring two classes and assign one method from one to another (`B.m = A.m`).  Then `B.m` and `A.m` will be equal (in fact, identical), so it is not possible to tell whether you looked the method up in `B` or in `A`.